# Apple documentation saved locally

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How can I access Apple documentation offline?

Comment: Thank you for your down votes! t's amazing how question gets so many down votes when answer has positive votes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Xcode** -> **Preferences** -> **Components** -> **Document** -> Download which you want.

You can search offline in **Xcode** -> **Help** -> **Documentation and API Reference**